# iOS, objective c throw exception at the very start

Tags: objective-c, exception, ios5

In the app delegade i get an exception and i don't have any idea why.
Here is the code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; \\ throw exception on this line
    return YES;
}
```

The exception is as follow:

```
Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT"
```

when the actual exception shows on main.m(i didn't create it nor see it):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

thanks!

Comment: Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT"

Comment: Is this a Single View template app, without ARC and without storyboard? I just tried and I get the same error?

Comment: In this project i have to uncheck all, So yes its single view when all is uncheck

Answer (score 1):

Check the xib files. Look through all Referenced Outlets and check if you are linking against a property that doesn't exist.

You might also want to add an Exception to your project (Xcode 4.2):

- open Breakpoint Navigator
- "+" at the bottom left corner